# How to keep text centered in an inactive input field?

Tags: html, css, input

I would like to have text centered in an input field when I click away from the field. Right now when I write something inside the field it starts from the center - that's good. Now I would like to keep it centered when I move away from the field or go to another one. Is it possible? Thanks for your help.

Bonus points: Is it possible to move up the bottom border of the input box? Let's say 2pxs up so that it would line perfectly with the text around the field?

```css
input[type=text] {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px black dotted;
  width: 100px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Write something in here: <input type="text">. Thanks!
</p>
```

Comment: You set text align center to the focus state of the input, was there a reason that you cannot set this to the normal state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `text-align:center` in the `input[type=text]` instead of the `input[type=text]:focus`

```css
input[type=text] {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px black dotted;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;
  
}
```

```html
<p>
  Write something in here: <input type="text">. Thanks!
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What a simple solution! 

Now, do you perhaps know how to move the bottom border? Or if it's worth doing that at all...

Comment: @KrzysztofDelestowicz Move it how?

Comment: @IronFlare move it so that the bottom border would align with the text around in a straight line.

Comment: @KrzysztofDelestowicz I don't know how to do it, and to be honest, I don't think its worth the hassle as it might cause the text inside the input field to move up too.

Comment: @KrzysztofDelestowicz. Welcome to StackOverflow. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.